# Error when generating Jhipster hello world first App. Getting ERROR! Error: spawn git ENOENT

Tags: mysql, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm-install, jhipster

I am a complete beginner using JHipster.
I would like to use it to connect a backend API node server to connect to a MySQL server at the backend and use a React front end that I already have.

When generating a JHipster project on Vs Code terminal, I selected the following for my server backend.

? Which *type* of application would you like to create? **Monolithic application (recommended for simple projects)**

? What is the base name of your application? **myserver**

? Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux? **No**

? What is your default Java package name? **com.testing.myserver**

? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? **JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)**

? Which *type* of database would you like to use? **SQL (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, MSSQL)**

? Which *production* database would you like to use? **MySQL**

? Which *development* database would you like to use? **H2 with disk-based persistence**

? Which cache do you want to use? (Spring cache abstraction) **Hazelcast (distributed cache, for multiple nodes, supports rate-limiting for gateway applications)**

? Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? **Yes**

? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? **Maven**

? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? **No**

? Which other technologies would you like to use? **API first development using OpenAPI-generator**

? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? **React**

? Do you want to generate the admin UI? **Yes**

? Would you like to use a Bootswatch theme (https://bootswatch.com/)? **Default JHipster**

? Would you like to enable internationalization support? **No**

? Please choose the native language of the application **English**

I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMRr9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says that JHipster was unable to launch `git` command. So, you should install it and make sure it is found in your PATH when you run it from VS Code terminal.

Comment: Thank you so much. I installed git while VS Code was already running. I had to restart VS Code to get the **git --version**  to run on the VS Code powershell and subsequently proceed with the configuration and initialisation. Thanks, Gael